# Nested States in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am try to achieve a cascading route using Angular UI-Router. Here is my code,

```
$stateProvider
            .state('billing', {
                url: '/billing',
                templateUrl: 'app/billing/billing.html',
                controller: 'BillingCtrl',
                abstract: true,
                resolve: {
                    currentUser: ['$state', '$stateParams', 'Auth',
                        function ($state, $stateParams, Auth) {
                            return Auth.getCurrentUser().$promise.then(function (user) {
                                return user;
                            });
                        }]
                }
            })
            .state('billing.table', {
                url: '/table',
                templateUrl: 'app/billing/_table.html',
                controller: 'BillingCtrl',
                data: {
                    tables: [
                        {"id": 0, "name": "Table 0"},
                        {"id": 1, "name": "Table 1"},
                        {"id": 2, "name": "Table 2"},
                        {"id": 3, "name": "Table 3"}
                    ]
                }
            })
            .state('billing.table.bill', {
                url: '/bill/:tableId/:covers',
                templateUrl: 'app/billing/_billing.html',
                controller: 'BillingCtrl',
                parent:'billing'
            })
            .state('billing.takeout', {
                url: '/takeout',
                templateUrl: 'app/billing/_takeout.html',
                controller: 'BillingCtrl'
            })
            .state('billing.delivery', {
                url: '/delivery',
                templateUrl: 'app/billing/_delivery.html',
                controller: 'BillingCtrl'
            });
```

Basically, it starts with the '`billing.table`' state which renders a group of Table Objects. When the User clicks on 'Goto Table' I have an Event function which fires $state.go(route) which transitions it to the '`billing.table.bill`' state. Everything works fine till here.

**First Problem:**
What I am trying to achieve and am unable to wrap my head around is, how do I make the the child state sticky, ie. `/billing/bill/1/2` always redirects to `/billing/table` whenever I hit enter on my address bar. I want `/billing/bill/1/2` to be sticky so that whenever the user enters this URL on the address bar it should resolve to this state. I have also tried using ui-router-extras with DSR. It still doesn't work.

**Second Problem:**
I want my child states to render in the Parent state ui-view definition, basically I want it to replace the parent view template and replace it with the child view template. To achieve this I have set `parent:'billing'` in the `billing.table.bill` child state. This works fine, but is it related to my first problem.

Some insight would be really grateful.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
Solved the problem. It was not working with `$state.go()`. Using ui-sref to link all child state resolved all states perfectly.

Comment: I don't understand.  For instance, you want `/billing/bill/1/2` to redirect to `/billing/table`?  But `/billing/bill/1/2` doesn't match any of your states. The `billing.table.bill` state should have a url that looks like `/billing/table/bill/:tableId/:covers`.  Can you rephrase what behavior you want with regards to your URLs?

Comment: The reverse is happening. Since, `/billing/table` (`billing.table`) -> `/billing/bill/1/2` (`billing.table.bill`). Whenever, I enter `/billing/bill/1/2` on the address bar, it should resolve to `billing.table.bill` state. The tableID is coming from `billing.table`; `data` custom object which the child state `billing.table.bill` inherits.

Comment: But `/billing/bill/1/2` does not map to the states you have shown.  `/billing/table/bill/1/2` would map to `billing.table.bill` however.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisT. I have managed to get it working using ui-sref to link child states. It wasn't working with `$state.go(route, $stateParams)`

Comment: FYI, ui-sref uses $state.go() internally.